# Rails pins: How does the pin id work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Using Ruby on Rails I have generated a pins controller and would like to understand how the pin `id` works after destroying a pin.

The first pin I created has a pin `id` of 1, the second has a pin id of `2`. After destroying the second pin and creating a new one, the last one I created has a pin `id` of 3.

Why doesn't the pin created after destroying the second pin have an `id` of 2? Is there a way to set it to that?

Comment: I assume this is because of associations. Why do you want it to be this way? The int takes up the same space as a 2, a 3 or a 100. If doing this is important to you then you can make the ID anything you want by setting it manually.

Comment: If you are developing your app and the auto incrementing bothers you, you can truncate you table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `id`s of the database records are usually auto incremented if unless specified. That's why, everytime you delete a record and then create a new record, then the new record gets a next number as its `id`.

Yes, you can update the record if you want to set the `id` to something else.

For example, you have a `Pin` model which has `id` and `name` attributes.

You can create a pin like this:

```
pin = Pin.create(name: 'Pin1')
```

So, `it will get id = 1`. But, if you destroy this pin object and re-create another one in a similar fashion:

```
pin = Pin.create(name: 'Pin1')
```

`it will get id = 2` and so on.

But, you can update it's `id` attribute if you want like this (Although, in real-life application you don't want to do that!):

```
pin.id = 1
pin.save
```

Now, `it's id is 1 again`.

So, theoretically it's possible, but you should not modify the database record IDs manually in a real-life application.

Comment: Additional information: 1) Some databases (like MS SQL) may keep deleted rows. Or you may set up an auditing system of your own. You'll need a way to reference deleted entries. 2) `id`s are not necessarily integers. Some databases (like MongoDB) use a timestamped hash-like value by default.